# How to set state immediately in global scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a Select component, which is basically a dropdown. When I choose one of it's item I see that id doesn't change and still remains of the previously selected item's id. but if I re-select it again then id updates.

Here is the code

```
const EditBookingDetailsModal = () => {
  const { modals, toggleModal, T } = useUI()
  const { laundry } = useLaundryContext()
  const { currentReservation, handleRecalculateReservationAmount, setState} = useReservationsContext()
  const {  vehicleBodyTypeId } = currentReservation as IReservationDetails
  const bodyTypes: ICarBodyType[] = laundry?.bodyTypes || []
  const [vehicleBodyId, setVehicleBodyId] = useState(vehicleBodyTypeId)
  const generateBodyTypesOptions = () => bodyTypes.map((bodyType) => ({
    label: bodyType.name,
    value: bodyType.id
  }))
  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={modals.editReservationDetailsModal.isOpened}
      onClose={() => {
        toggleModal("editReservationDetailsModal", false)
        setState({ modifiedPrice: null })
      }}
      title={T("booking.details.edit.modal.title")}
      styles={{
        headerPadding: "20px 15px 20px 23px",
        width: "566px",
        bodyPadding: "0px 0px 0px 0px",
      }}
    >
      <Box paddingBottom={"40px"}>
        <Flex
          gap={"30px"}
          padding="14px 23px 20px 23px"
          borderBottom={"1px solid #E9F2FD "}
        >
          <FormControl width={"55%"}>
            <FormLabel id="auto" text={T("booking.details.edit.auto")} />
            <Select
              value={vehicleBodyId|| ""}
              onChange={(e: any) => {
                setVehicleBodyId(e.value)
                  handleRecalculateReservationAmount(selectedVehicleId, selectedServiceId, vehicleBodyId)
              }}
              options={generateBodyTypesOptions()}
              inputStyles={{
                height: "60px",
              }}
              // placeholderStyles={{ fontSize: "var(--chakra-fontSizes-m)" }}
              
            />  
          </FormControl>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

This is greatly reduced code and minimal example where this behavior still occurs. Main thing is happening in onChange attribute. I wanna know how to extract `e.value` and make it available in the global scope in order to use it in another Select Components, because I have three Select Components and in each one i have to make request `handleRecalculateReservationAmount(selectedVehicleId, selectedServiceId, vehicleBodyId)`

Comment: If you console log e you will see you need to access e.current.value or e.target.value

Comment: when i console log e it is key value pair array, like this  e = [
              { label: "Sedan", value: 1},
              { label: "Jeep", value: 2},
              { label: "Hathback", value: 3},
              { label: "Motorcycle", value: 4},
              {label: "Other", value: 5},
              ]

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the target to access the value like e.target.value instead of e.value secondly if you are using MUI select there might be a chance that the onChange function has 2 params in it like `(e, value)=>{ //statements }` instead of `(e)=>{ ///statements }`, which you might need.

Comment: e.target.value is undefined because my when i console .log e it is object like this {Label: "Sedan", value: 1}. and I am not using MUI.

Comment: can you share the Select component you made ?

Comment: it's handmade component and it's too big to write it's code here. But it is not important, I have tried the same scenario with just basic select component and another libraries' components and the result is the same. When I select some item from the dropdown i fire post request to the backend, in which i need to pass 3 values such as vehicleId, serviceId and vehicleBodyTypeId, respectively i have 3 Select Components with the same functionality, so if you understand you would have already guessed that i need to access e.value in another two Select Components.